# Validate C# project file against a template during build

Tags: continuous-integration, tfsbuild

I know that you can create a template project to ensure that certain required settings (for ex: code analysis, treat warnings as errors, platforms, etc.) are set in a new project.

I want to enforce this as a part of the CI process i.e. in the build I want to validate the C# project files against a template (or an XML file) and cause a build failure if the project files don't conform to it. I need suggestions and ideas on how this can be achieved.

I want to try this with TFS 2010 and VS 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am writing a custom task to search for all the C# project files and compare the Xml structure of the Template project file with the Actual project file and report any difference as error.

Answer (score 0):

I usually tackle this by customizing my build process to run Code Analysis/StyleCop/etc against all projects regardless of project settings.

Likewise for Treat Warnings as Errors.  I just override the proejct settings at the build-level so that no matter what people do to the projects I know that everything I want to run is being run at build time.